# gridview, objectdatasource selected event not running on postback

Tags: asp.net

I have a simple asp.net web page with a gridview, objectdatasource, and button that just postsback.

I'm handling the `objectdatasource_selected` event which runs fine the first time the page loads. However, when I click the button to do the postback `objectdatasource_selected` event does not run.

What can I check in order to resolve this?

Comment: Aren't you by chance rebinding on postback? This could cause you events go astray.

Comment: There's no code in the code behind. The select method of the object data source calls a get method in the business layer.